# Strange behavior - Console stops printing

Tags: c++, boost, console

I have encountered some strange behavior which I can't explain.

I'm using boost log v1 to  log to the console using `wtext_ostream_backend` and to a file using `wtext_file_backend`.

Everything usually work fine, but just the other day the application stopped printing to the console, though it continued to log to file. When I looked in the file for the line where the console stopped printing i noted something strange:

```
0: [02/07/12 13:49:38] [07437538] [info]    Client 10.28.62.1 was disconnected
1: [02/07/12 13:49:40] [07437538] [info]    Received message from 10.50.128.77: [02/07/12 13:49:40] [07437538] [info]    Sent message to 10.50.128.77: 400 ERROR\r\n2[02/07/12 13:49:40] [07437538] [info]    Received message from 10.28.48.9: VERSION\r\n
4: [02/07/12 13:49:40] [07437538] [info]    Received message from 10.28.48.9: VERSION\r\n
3: [02/07/12 13:49:40] [00C79D10] [debug]   Executed command: VersionCommand
```

If you look at line `1:` you can see that `Received message from 10.50.118.77:` abruptly end and the next message is written without line breaks. Which otherwise never is the case.

The last thing the console printed was `Received message from 10.50.118.77:`.

Any ideas what might cause this? Could it be some weird character that followed `Received message from 10.50.118.77:` that messes everything up? How can avoid/tolerate such characters?

Comment: If you look at that line of the file in a hex editor, is there anything odd there?

Comment: Most likely some nonprintable characters in the received message that messed up the log file. Other  thing might be, if you have a multithereaded application, multiple threads trying to write to log at the same time maybe?

Comment: @BrooksMoses: Nothing strange there, though it might just might mean that it failed to print it.

Comment: Just to clearify, the main problem here is that the console stopped printing, not that there is no linebreak in the file (though that is also wierd).

Comment: @GrigoryJavadyan: Can a character mess up `std::wcout`? It is multithreaded, though boost log v1 should be thread-safe.

Comment: @wonag it probably can. FWIW, try `cat /usr/bin/sh` and it will most likely mess up your terminal.

Comment: @GrigoryJavadyan: Is there any generic way to detect and filter such chars? I'm printing using UTF16.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't terminate the string with a null char properly.