# Check if all characters in UTF16 string are valid?

Tags: c++, string, utf-16

I have a problem where I have UTF16 strings (`std::wstring`) that might have "invalid" characters which causes my console terminal to stop printing (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219823/strange-behavior-console-stops-printing#comment11609413_9219823)).

I wonder if there is a fast way to check all the characters in a string and replace any invalid chars with `?`.

I know I could do something along these lines with a regex, but it would be difficult to make it validate all valid chars, and also slow. Is there e.g. a numeric range for the char codes that I might use e.g. all char codes between 26-5466 is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use `std::ctype<wchar_t>` to determine if a character is printable:

```
std::local loc;
std::replace_if(string.begin(), string.end(),
                [&](wchar_t c)->bool { return !std::isprint(c, loc); }, L'?');
```

Comment: That should be "..., u'?')"', not 'L'. 'u' is for 16-bit, 'U' is for 32-bit, and 'L' is for wchar_t, which can be 16-bit or 32-bit depending on the OS. So, for portability use 'u', as the question was UTF-16. And as UTF-16 can be 2 or 4 octets. And  loc would have had to been set with loc("en_US.UTF-16") first.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is not related to the validity of characters, but to the capability of the console to print them.

The definition UNICODE does to "printable" does not necessarily coincide to the effective capability of the console itself to "print".

Character like '€' are "printable" but -for example- not on winXP consoles.